# Shrink x limits in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a CSV file containing data I need to print (simple scatter plot). However, I need to show only half of them on the x-axis (I need to hide the right part of the plot). In other term, I need the following code to work.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        enlarge x limits={value=-0.5,upper},  % <-- THE NEGATIVE VALUE DOES NOT WORK
        enlarge y limits={value=0.05,upper},
    ]
        \addplot table[x=x,y=y,col sep=comma]{table.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Another way of understanding it is to set `xmax=0.5\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}` as I know that the smallest x-value is 0, but this, of course, does not work as it cycles.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cane.g. be done with the following code. Hopefully this is self-explanatory. If not, let me know and I'll add some comments.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
    \begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data.dat}
        x   y
        1   5
        2   3
        3   6
        4   4
        5   0
        6   1
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotstableread[]{data.dat}{\mytable}
        \newcommand{\findMax}[1]{
            \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mytable}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\LastRowNo{\pgfplotsretval-1}
            \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={#1}]{\sorted}{\mytable}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\LastRowNo}{#1}\of{\sorted}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\tempMax}{\pgfplotsretval}
        }
        \findMax{x}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmax = \tempMax/2,
    ]
        \addplot table {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Brilliant! It worked perfectly. I added the option `col sep=comma` to \pgfplotstableread to directly load my CSV. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what I am doing, so use this answer at own risk. Data and output is the same as in answer by @Stefan Pinnow.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data.dat}
x,   y
1,   5
2,   3
3,   6
4,   4
5,   0
6,   1
\end{filecontents}
    
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
execute at end survey={\pgfmathparse{0.5*\csname pgfplots@xmax\endcsname} \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@xmax\endcsname=\pgfmathresult},
enlarge x limits={false,lower},
]
\addplot table[x=x, y=y, col sep=comma]{data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! It also works on my side, though it raises the common warning `Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!`. Thank you!

Comment: Yes - my mistake. Delete the `;` in the option so it reads: `execute at end survey={\pgfmathparse{0.5*\csname pgfplots@xmax\endcsname} \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@xmax\endcsname=\pgfmathresult},`